# How to call a function continuously in background in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, background-process

I know it might seem a repeated question, but I want to call a method to report geolocation position every minute as long as the application is open. Other answers recommended using CountDownTimer class. Is there a better way in Android to repeatedly call a function in background?

Answer (score 2):

No idea who suggested a count down timer, but in Android you can use Services namely the Background Service. [See here](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider something like an [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) - which will run periodically, i.e. every minute to execute an Intent

The risk you run, if something is continuously running, is it will be shut down by the OS.

Alternatively, if you're checking network connectivity etc then you can look into BroadCast receivers - and there's no need to run continuously in the background.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are getting the location. If you use play services you can take advantage of the [LocationRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest) class. For more information about how to use play services to get the location, please have a look at [this training](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) put together by Google.

Hope this helps.